# Sum of series: Proof by induction

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{2^i} = 2- \frac{n+2}{2^n}$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$

Base Case: $n=1$

$ \implies i=1$

$ \implies \frac{1}{2} = 2- \frac{3}{2}$

base case holds true ($1=1$)

I.H:

it's true for $n=k\in\Bbb N$

Then;

For $n=k+1$

$$\implies\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{i}{2^i} = 2- \frac{(k+1)+2}{2^{k+1}}$$

$$\implies\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{i}{2^i} = 2- \frac{(k+1)+2}{2^k\cdot2^1}$$

$$\implies\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{i}{2^i} = 2- \frac{k+3}{2^k}\cdot\frac{1}{2^1}$$

I'm not sure how to procced next

Comment: $\frac{i}{2i}=\frac{1}{2}$... no?

Comment: I guess the main term shoud be $\frac{i}{2^i}$, please improve formatting.

Comment: Suggestion - use `\implies` and `$$...$$` for better readability

Comment: Anyway the statement is straightforward to prove by induction, it is enough to check that $$ 2-\frac{n+2}{2^n} + \frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}} = 2-\frac{n+3}{2^{n+1}}.$$

Comment: Assuming that the term in the summation is $\frac{i}{2^i}$, this is an "Arithmetico-Geometric Series". There is a general result for the summation $a + (a+d)r + (a+2d)r^2 + (a + 3d)r^3 + \cdots + (a+(n-1)d)r^{n-1}$. Wiki has an article on this. Put the proper values in the formula and you should be able to get the result.

Comment: @TheGamer  You are not doing this right!  Your first equation in the Inductive step is what you *need* to show .. so don't *assume* this. This is a very common mistake.  What you need to do is: *start* with the LHS, and *end* with the RHS, *using* the Inductive Hypothesis. See George's Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looks, you haven't fully understood the induction argument. What you have to do is start with one side of the formula with $k=n+1$, and assuming it is true for $k=n$ (the induction hypothesis), arrive at the other side of the formula for $k=n+1$.

Here's an example proof:

Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i}{2^i}=2-\frac{n+2}{2^n}$:

Base case ($n=1$):

$\sum_{i=1}^{1}\frac{i}{2^i}=\frac{1}{2^1}=\frac12$

$2-\frac{1+2}{2^1}=2-\frac{3}{2}=\frac12$

So the formula is true for $n=1$.

In the next step we assume that the formula is true for all numbers up to $n$. We must show that the formula is also true for $n+1$. By doing this, if it is true for $n+1$, then it must be true for $n+2$, etc. This in turn implies it is true for all natural numbers.

Induction step: Assume the formula holds true for all integers up to $n$. We need to show it also holds true for $n+1$. This means that we have to start with $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{i}{2^i}=...$, and end with $...=2-\frac{n+3}{2^{n+1}}$.

Here is the full proof:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{i}{2^i}\overset{\mathrm{(a)}}{=}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i}{2^i}+\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\overset{\mathrm{(b)}}{=}2-\frac{n+2}{2^n}+\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\overset{\mathrm{(c)}}{=}2-\frac{2n+4}{2^{n+1}}+\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}$$
$$=2+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}(-2n-4+n+1)=2+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}(-n-3)=2-\frac{n+3}{2^{n+1}}$$
Where in (a) I used the definition of the sum at $n+1$, in (b) I used the induction hypothesis (ie: that the formula up to $n$ holds true), and in (c) and thereafter I factorised and simplified.

Comment: oh k thanks and is my base case wrong?

Comment: You induction argument is wrong; you have assumed that the formula is true for $n=k+1$, but your hypothesis, ie: what you assume to be true, is that it is true up to only $k$

Comment: can u check my updated I.H is that what u meant

Comment: No that was not what I meant. I rewrote my answer to give you a better model of how an induction proof should look like

Comment: i dont get how u got the definition of (a)

Comment: If you understand what the sigma sum notation represents: $\sum_{i=1}^na_i=a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_{n-1}+a_n$. So naturally,$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_i=a_1+a_2+...+a_n+a_{n+1}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right) + a_{n+1}$